# Facebook Conversions API implementation with Google Tag Manager Server-Side

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-tag-manager, conversions-api, google-tag-manager-server-side

Hi, I have a question concerning the implementation of Facebook Conversions API via Google Tag Manager Server-Side.

We are using DNN /EVOQ CMS which is a .net application.
Everything else is in place concerning Facebook Pixel and Business manager. 
I also tested it on the Graph API and it worked fine.
It’s just the last step that is missing.

I know one way to implement the Facebook Conversions API is with Node.js Business SDK.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api

My Question:
If you use Google Tag Manager Server-Side, do you still need to add the Node.js Business SDK ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node sdk is to send FB conversions directly to FB.

In your case, you send all the FB conversion info with the hit to your GTM endpoint and then you make a custom http request tag and retranslate all the info you've got from your backend into a proper FB conversion request.

That's pretty much it.